# Kohana ----- form

Tags: php, forms, kohana, kohana-3

There is `Member.php` controller which contain this:

```
    $post = $this->request->post();
    if($post){
        $member = ORM::factory('Member');
        $member->values($post);
        $member->save();
    }
```

And there is also in view `news.php`.
The point is i dont't know how form in this view is working and how to connect with controller. I mean what should input contain.

```
 echo Form::open('Member', array('method'=>'get'));
 echo Form::label('username', 'username');
 echo Form::input('username' );
 echo Form::submit(NULL, 'Post');
 echo Form::close();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the **method** argument on `Form::open` to **post**. e.g.

```
Form::open('Member', array('method'=>'post'));
```

Also, the first argument to `Form::submit` is the text you want on the button, whilst the second argument is the value that will be submitted. e.g.

```
Form::submit('Save Details', NULL);
```